# How to avoid "noise" when setting pixels of image in unsafe code

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, unsafe

I am creating (then altering) a bitmap using "unsafe" code in a C# winforms project. This is done every 30ms or so. The problem I'm having is that "noise" or random pixels will show up sometimes in the resulting bitmap where I did not specifically change anything.

For example, I create a bitmap of 100x100. Using `BitmapData` and `LockBits`, I iterate through the bitmap and change certain pixels to a specific color. Then I `UnlockBits` and set a picturebox to use the image. All of the pixels I set are correct, but pixels that I did not specifically set are sometimes seemingly random colors.

If I set every pixel, the noise disappears. However, for performance reasons, I would prefer only to set the minimum number.

Can anyone explain why it does this?

Here is some example code:

```
// Create new output bitmap
Bitmap Output_Bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100);

// Lock the output bitmap's bits
Rectangle Output_Rectangle = new Rectangle(
    0,
    0,
    Output_Bitmap.Width,
    Output_Bitmap.Height);
BitmapData Output_Data = Output_Bitmap.LockBits(
    Output_Rectangle,
    ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
    PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

const int PixelSize = 4;
unsafe
{
    for (int y = 0; y < Output_Bitmap.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Output_Bitmap.Width/2; x++)
        {
            Byte* Output_Row = (Byte*)Output_Data.Scan0 + y * Output_Data.Stride;
            Output_Row[(x * PixelSize) + 2] = 255;
            Output_Row[(x * PixelSize) + 1] = 0;
            Output_Row[(x * PixelSize) + 0] = 0;
        }
    }
}

// Unlock the bits
Output_Bitmap.UnlockBits(Output_Data);

// Set picturebox to use bitmap
pbOutput.Image = Output_Bitmap;
```

In this example, I am only setting the left half of the image (Width/2 in the inner for loop). The right half will have random noise on an otherwise black background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is somewhat speculative, since I'm not privy to the implementation details of any of these classes, but I have a guess.

When you call `new Bitmap(100, 100)`, the memory region that represents the bitmap's pixels is *uninitialized*, and therefore contains whatever random garbage was in those memory locations before it was allocated. The first time that you write to the bitmap you then set a only a subset of the locations, and the others show the random memory garbage.

If this is the case, then you must be sure to write to *every* pixel in the new `Bitmap` the first time you update it. Subsequent updates only need to update the changed pixels.

Comment: Just after creating Output_Bitmap, I have also tried a quick `using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Output_Bitmap)) g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, Output_Bitmap.Width, Output_Bitmap.Height);` but the same result occurs.

Comment: @JYelton, that might not work because you are later asking for a specific pixel format, which I could imagine would require a new allocation if it is different from whatever the default was?

Comment: I'm running two loops now; one to set all pixels to black and another to set the specific ones. It seems to work well, although obviously the performance is taking a hit. @Doug I'll check out the zero memory method you linked, it might take the place of the first loop. Thanks.

Comment: @JYelton - another optimization that you might consider is to only call `LockBits` on the region that you intend to update (but update the entire region that you locked). I suspect that the problem actually occurs when the memory is marshalled to/from the device context, and you'll save a lot by locking the smallest possible region.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create a graphics object over the bitmap and place a `Graphics.Clear()` call after you create your bitmap to avoid undefined state of the bitmap memory.

You should also change from using `Format32bppRgb` to `Format32PbppRgb` because you're not setting the alpha byte.  Either that or switch to the 24 bpp format.

Comment: There is no method `.Clear()` for a bitmap object.

Comment: True, however, if you create a graphics object over the bitmap object and call graphics.clear(color.black) you should be able to clear the bitmap.

Comment: Also, do you mean `Format32bppPArgb` instead of `Format32PbppRgb`?

Comment: Using 24bpp is probably somewhat better since I don't need alpha. Thanks for the suggestion. However, the flickering/random pixels still occur.